# Execute Python script in terminal fullscreen

Tags: python, terminal

how do I write/execute a Python script full screen at the terminal.
I want to write a small Programm which shoud be shown like "vim", "sl", or "nano".

Answer (score 0):

As fas as I can understand from your question, you can make the terminal to be fullscreen by pressing `F11` (at least in Ubuntu)